# Get video URL from Youtube API

Tags: java, json, youtube-api

I have a JSON from YouTube API.

Here is my JSON in this [link](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=natok%202015&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyCojCp66RLS9OY8hOwnW0UWLNdC56z24Os)

I am having trouble to get image from it. I unable to Show Image.

I am trying for it around 10days but i can't solve this.Can Anyone please solve this out

here is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String imgURL = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uU-uRElXM3A/default.jpg";

static String VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
static String TITLE = "title";
//static String DESCRIPTION = "description";
static String THUMBNAILS = "thumbnails";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Your Youtube Video is");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address



        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=natok+2015&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyCojCp66RLS9OY8hOwnW0UWLNdC56z24Os");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                JSONObject jsonObjId = jsonobject.getJSONObject("id");
                map.put("videoId", jsonObjId.getString("videoId"));

                JSONObject jsonObjSnippet = jsonobject.getJSONObject("snippet");
                 map.put("title", jsonObjSnippet.getString("title"));

                //JSONObject jsonObjThumbnail = jsonObjSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
               // String imgURL = jsonobject.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getString("url"); //use "medium/high" instead of default as required.
                JSONObject jsonObjThumbnail = jsonobject.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
                String imgURL = jsonobject.getJSONObject("default").getString("url");









                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: see the updated anser, it will help you, sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get image URL from the JSON, please use the code:
after the line `JSONObject jsonObjSnippet = jsonobject.getJSONObject("snippet");`

```
JSONObject jsonObjThumbnail = jsonobject.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
String imgURL = jsonObjThumbnail.getJSONObject("default").getString("url");//use "medium/high" instead of default as required.
map.put("url", imgURL);
```

UPDATE: 
you will get imgURL as String;
Eg: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uU-uRElXM3A/default.jpg

I think you forgot to add imageURL to "map",

Comment: what is the imgURL means & what is the value of imgURL

Comment: i found 12-14 17:56:27.913 6946-6966/amit.jsonparsewithimage E/Error: No value for thumbnails this error

Comment: you will get imgURL as String; Eg: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uU-uRElXM3A/default.jpg

Comment: can you post the stack trace? what problem are you facing now?

Comment: in my previous comment i post it

Comment: hi, I just made an update to my answer, please try it and let me know if still u face problem,

Answer (score 0):

To parse your json you should first define JSONArray object by doing:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
```

Then you need to loop throughout your json array to build one:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("array-key");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject newObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: By saying images I guess you mean to the thumbnails, so if you are parsing your json all you should do is get to the items array, and there to snippet and than thumbnails.

Comment: can u please prove a sample for me